linux header <linux/sysctl.h> deprecated
is linux header <linux/sysctl.h> deprecated ?
I read this on man 2 sysctl:

This system call first appeared in Linux 1.3.57.  It was removed in Linux 5.5; glibc support was removed in version 2.32.

I misunderstood this line?
How to change system parameters in future (after removal)?

Keep reading. Look for a "Use ... instead".

oh , yes i see that line , you know this is too hard , for example with this command i can found all available configs : sysctl -a , now should i search in /proc/sys directory ?

The sysctl -a command still works. (presumably by walking the file system) It's just the syscall that's no longer usable. But yes, the functionality is now accessed by poking around in the directory.


It has the deprecated attribute.

[[deprecated]] int _sysctl(struct __sysctl_args *args);


The description states that it no longer exists on current kernels.


This system call no longer exists on current kernels!


"NOTES" suggest using /proc/sys interface:


Use of this system call was long discouraged: since Linux 2.6.24,
uses of this system call result in warnings in the kernel log,
and in Linux 5.5, the system call was finally removed.  Use the
/proc/sys interface instead.

and the man page links to this: proc.
So yes, it is deprecated.
